# requestDispatcher.forward forward does not work, but response.sendRedirect does. Does anyone know why?

Tags: jsp, servlets, redirect, forward

I have built a jsp page to display content dynamically allowing for commenting.
The jsp page may activate a PostComment servlet to insert data in a database.
The servlet then redirects back to the jsp page, which is found, and displays content and the form but not prior comments.
I can get correct functionality by using response.sendRedirect, but am confused as
to why request dispatching doesn't work.  I have put below the relevant servlets and jsp.
I have eliminated code I think is not relevant, but would be happy to include more if needed.  The three components are below.

To sumarize.  If I call A, everything works fine.  A grabs content, puts up the form, and displays prior comments(servlet B).
If the user enters a comment, A will call servlet C, which will redirect back to A.
If C goes back to A using Response.sendRedirect, it works, if C goes back to A using requestDispatcher.forward, A functions but does not include the results of C

A. MAIN viewarticle.jsp (Display some content(5-7) provide a form to add comments(9-16) display prior comments(18-20)  work fine if called directly

```
<html><head><TITLE>Article</TITLE><link rel="stylesheet" href="../default.css"></head>
    <body class="main">
        <h1>Article:  <%= request.getParameter("article") %></h1>
        <% String fname = request.getParameter("article"); %><% String fullname = "/dswva/articles/"+fname+".jsp"; %><% String relname = "../articles/"+fname+".jsp"; %>

        <jsp:include page = '<%= relname %>' flush="true">
        <jsp:param name="bull" value="shit"/>
        </jsp:include>

        <h3>To make a comment, enter it below?</h3>
        <form name="PostComm" method="post" action="/dswva/servlet/PostComm">
        <input type="hidden" name='article' value='<%= fname %>'>
        <input type="hidden" name='fullname' value='<%= fullname %>'>
        <input type="hidden" name="user" value= <%= request.getRemoteUser() %>>
        <p><textarea name="comment" rows="9" cols="70"></textarea></p>
        <p>    <input type="submit" value="Submit My Comment" name="submit">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear Form" name="reset"> </p>
        </form>
        <h2>Comments made previously:</h2>
        <jsp:include page="/servlet/ViewComments" flush="true" >
        <jsp:param name="fullname" value='<%= fullname %>'/>
        </jsp:include>
    </body>
</html>
```

B. Servlet to display comments on content -- works as advertized.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)   throws ServletException, IOException {
    DatabaseConnector con = new DatabaseConnector(DatabaseConnector.getDatabaseType());
    ResultSet rs = null;
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        StringBuffer SQL = new StringBuffer("SELECT ID,User,Date_Posted,Comment FROM ArtComment ");
        SQL.append("WHERE Article = '" + request.getParameter("fullname") + "' ORDER BY Date_Posted DESC");
        rs = con.selectSQL_RS(SQL.toString());
        if (rs != null) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                String userString = rs.getString("User");
                String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(rs.getObject("Date_Posted"));
                String CommentString = rs.getString("comment");
                out.println("<p>On " + dateString + ", " + userString + " said:</p>");
                out.println("<blockquote>" + CommentString + "</blockquote>");
            }
        } else {
            out.println("<h4>No Comments have been made to date on this article.</h4>");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        out.println("SQLException caught in viewcomments: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

C. Servlet to Post a comment and recall viewarticle.jsp -- after posting a new comment, the servlet is redirected (line 17-18) to the JSP page which function correctly except that it does not include prior comments.  If I use Response.sendRedirect (line 16), it works as expected

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)        throws ServletException, IOException {
    DatabaseConnector con1 = new DatabaseConnector(DatabaseConnector.getDatabaseType());
    try {
        con1 = new DatabaseConnector(DatabaseConnector.getDatabaseType());
        String madeBy = request.getRemoteUser();
        if (madeBy == null) {
            madeBy = request.getParameter("user")+"?";
        }
        String lComment = request.getParameter("comment");
        String lFullname = request.getParameter("fullname");
        String lArticle = request.getParameter("article");
        int display = 0;

        String SQL = "INSERT INTO artcomment (user,Comment, Article) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        con1.freeformSQL(SQL, new Object[]{madeBy, lComment, lFullname});
        con1.CleanUp();
        response.sendRedirect("/dswva/articles/viewArticle.jsp?article="+lArticle);
        // RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/articles/viewArticle.jsp?article=" + lArticle);
        //rd.forward(request, response);// Create the header for the resource info

    } finally {
    con1.CleanUp();
    }
}
```